# Randomizing a list with another lists index

Tags: python

I'm working on a quiz at the moment. I was wandering whether anyone can help me with an error i keep receiving. Here is my code:

```
num1 = num = 0
import random

questions = ["What is RAM?","what is ROM","What is a bundle of wires 
carrying data from one component to another?","What does the control unit 
do?"]

ans = [["Random access memory","real access memory","read access 
memory","readable access memory","A"],["Readable object memory","Random 
object memory","Read only memory","Read object memory","C"],
["Bus","Hardware","System software","Embedded systems","A"],["You type on 
it","It sends out control signals to other components","It calculates 
arithmetic problems","Regulates time and speed of computer functions","D"]]

for index in range(0, len(questions)):
    val = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    index = random.choice(val)
    print(questions[index])
    print("\nA:",ans[index][0],"\nB:",ans[index][1],"\nC:",ans[index]
      [2],"\nD:",ans[index][3],"")     
    pa = input("What is your answer?")
    if pa == ans[index][4]:
        num1, num = num1 + 1, num + 1
        print("Correct!\nYou have got",num1,"out of",num,"correct so far\n")
        questions.remove(questions[index])
        ans.remove(ans[index])
        val.remove(index)
    else:
        num = num + 1
        print("incorrect!\nThe correct answer was",ans[index][4],"Your 
         correct questions are Your incorrect questions are")
```

I'm trying to make it so that it asks the questions in a random order, and doesn't keep giving them questions with other questions answers. Anyone know how that could be done? 
Would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend consolidating the questions and answers into a single list; a list of tuples.

```
questions = [('What is RAM?', 'random access memory'), ('What is ROM?', 'read-only memory')]
```

Then to pick out a question, run

```
question = random.choice(questions)
```

Put together, it'll look pretty close to your original script:

```
import random

questions = [('What is RAM?', 'random access memory'), ('What is ROM?', 'read-only memory')]

while questions:
    question = random.choice(questions)

    print(question[0])
    user_response = input('Reponse> ')
    if user_response == question[1]:
        print('Correct!')
        questions.remove(question)
    else:
        print('Wrong!')
```

[demo](https://repl.it/JG0z)

Comment: Yes, try refreshing the page. It should read `questions.remove(question)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `random.shuffle` for the indices:

```
>>> sequence = list(range(len(questions)))
>>> random.shuffle(sequence)
>>> sequence
[2, 0, 3, 1, ....]
```

Then pick questions with

```
for index in sequence:
    question = questions[index]
```

Comment: im getting an error with range: "TypeError: 'range' object does not support item assignment"

Comment: @johnnu you have to use `sequence = list(range(len(questions))` in Python 3